# jquery for regexp doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i use a jquery for a input box to validate content of that 
i person who has worked before me make a file that name is comoon.js and that file support all another files.but when i write this code on (document).ready(function() like this

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#validate').keyup(function(){
      var i = $('input');
      (/http:\/\//).test(i.val()) && i.val(i.val().replace('http://',''));
    });
```

});

and i have input box like this

```
<input type="text" id="validate"  class="right" name="linkurl" maxlength="150" size="130"/>
```

but it doesnt work on this button what should i do and what is the problem and i know that js file loaded of all pages ...

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "jquery-ajax"? Is the input in question being created dynamically after an ajax call?

Comment: yeah exactly but my friend i use live function like .live('keyup' ........

Comment: Well the code you showed doesn't use `.live()`. See my answer for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have more than one input on your page the problem is this line:

```
var i = $('input');
```

...which sets `i` to a jQuery object containing *all* inputs on the page. Try instead:

```
var i = $(this);
```

...which will set `i` to a jQuery object containing just the element the event occurred on.

(Your code works when there is only one input.)

If the input in question is created dynamically after page load you'll have a second issue: you can't bind an event handler to an element that doesn't exist yet, but you can use a delegated event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on("keyup", '#validate', function(){
      var i = $(this);
      (/http:\/\//).test(i.val()) && i.val(i.val().replace('http://',''));
    });
});
```

Where ideally you'd replace `document` in `$(document).on("keyup", '#validate', ...` with the closest ancestor of "#validate" that exists on page load. If you're using a version of jQuery less than 1.7 use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (see the jQuery API doco for more info).

Comment: It worked fine for me with a dynamically created field here: http://jsfiddle.net/EMgE6/

Comment: another question can u help me to change regexp . i want chek 7 frist alpghabet if it dosent http:// then it add http:// to it for example

Comment: for exmaple if i wirte in inputbox www.example.com it  convert to http://www.example.com